# How to safely remove large amount of rows from big PostgreSQL table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, caching, query-optimization

I inherited a PostgreSQL table being used for caching purpose. The table has not been cleaned for long and is now massive -- **1.7 TB** in size with over **300 million row**. Most of the records are not used and should be cleaned. This table is being used in production live, with active queries every minute. It thus can't afford a long downtime. The table structure will be described below.

I am planning to clean up this table and keep only most recent records, e.g in the past 3 month. However, with table of this size, I think the normal delete and vacuum approach can break the database. I want a safe solution to clean up this big table. Can anyone help? Any advice?

Let's call this table **cache**. There are four columns, one of which is a creation timestamp. Details attached. PostgreSQL version:  psql version 9.2, server version 9.5. Only those records created in the past 3 months are needed. Older records should be removed from the table.

```
     Column  |            Type             |                         Modifiers
-------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
 id          | bigint                      | not null default nextval('cache_id_seq'::regclass)
 value       | text                        | not null
 created_ts  | timestamp without time zone | not null
```

My currently plan is:

- Firstly, create a backup table using the same structure, call it
  cache_backup. (e.g. copy cache table structure with NO data).
- Secondly, select from cache table only rows created in recent 3 months, and
  copy them to cache_backup.
- Finally, once the copy is done, I will drop the old table(cache), and
  rename cache_backup to cache.

My concern with this plan is, in the second step, select from the old big table can take very long, if can finish at all.

Any advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: You can try to create the cache_backup table to see how long it takes to create, which should tell you the downtime required for inserting new rows.  You should also check to see if there are any views that reference the cache table.  They will need to be re-defined if you decide to rename the existing table.

Comment: thanks @Jeremy I wonder while copying from the old table, which might take time, will query to the old table be delayed/blocked ?

Comment: @stevenyu530: selecting from a table won't block other selects on the table (nor insert, updates or deletes)

Comment: Try `SELECT count(*) FROM cache WHERE created_ts > now() - interval '3 months'` and see how long that query takes.  That will give you a rough idea of how long Step 2 will take (excluding the time it takes to insert).  However, the problem with this plan is: what happens to inserts between Step 2 and Step 3, that don't get into `cache_backup`?